# Wait for CouchDB container to start

Tags: visual-studio-code, ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric

I am using **IBM Blockchain vs code extension** to test fabric node js chain code. But when I start the IBM environment to run chaincode at the time I was facing an issue to start a CouchDB container. And only see 1 up the container.

Can anyone guide me?

**Error:**

```
[9/28/2020 5:12:48 PM] [INFO] FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for CouchDB container to start (13 retries left).
```

Comment: Delete all the existing fabric-related containers and images. Could you please share the version of vscode you are using?

Comment: I am using a 1.49.2 version of vscode.

Answer (score 0):

The newest VScode has some compatibility issues with the IBM Blockchain extension. Can you try deleting all the containers, images, and volumes of the Hyperledger Fabric.
And then downgrade the vscode IDE to 1.39 version.

You can find more about the issue here:

https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/issues/1124#issuecomment-671261902